# Site Crawlers and Color CSS

Tags: css

I wasn't able to find information on this through search, nor was I able to find a possible solution. Perhaps I'm using the wrong words.

While using a few site speed tools, I decided to play around with testing common sites. Larger sites, just for the sake of it.

During that experiment, I noticed something. All the big sites had full-color snapshots. Mine, by comparison, was black and white. Properly formatted with flex, margin, right down to the font types and sizes. No color.

I use an in-house script which minifies several CSS files and flattens them into one CSS file. The crawler does acknowledge the CSS formatting. Without CSS, any site would like a bundle of nonsense.

A crawler seeing black and white isn't the problem. The concern is that it sees others in full color. For the most part, I just want to understand why the difference exists and how they work with color. It'd be great if there's a solution allowing crawlers to view the site properly. For kicks.

Comment: Crawlers just see text. If you want to see what a crawler sees, download a text browser like Lynx for example and browse with that.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of why other sites' color CSS is visible in the same snapshot area as mine, which is black and white. I've read that information several times, but it takes on a new meaning when it seems to behave differently in the form of a snapshot.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to start a new line but ended up posting instead. My guess as to why you see differences is probably because some of the CSS (like flex for example) isn't supported by the primitive crawlers' CSS parser.

Comment: Hmmm... but since the entire site is a tiered series of flexboxes, wouldn't that mean none of it would be properly formatted in general, on top of not being colored? Nearly every element on the site is classified as a flexbox.

Comment: Hard to say since I don't know how your HTML and CSS looks like. It could also be that the CSS is just not loading for crawlers due to one reason or the other.

Comment: All section, div, a, and of course the standard html/head/title/meta/script/link/body tags in terms of HTML. CSS, I always use either class or ID, occasionally * to apply to everything under a specific element. Thing is, the snapshot doesn't even acknowledge basic CSS like color. I'd understand issue with, say, radial-gradient on background if the snapshot-generator doesn't recognize CSS3, but basic backgrounds and colors should still show. In terms of how it's structured: The format for a specific section of the site is first, the color is second. So the color is between two format sections.

Comment: What that means is that -if- the issue had something to do with a flex-box in the first section which might trigger a 'failure' of receiving the rest of the CSS, it should break after the first section and, alongside not displaying the color of the same section... frankly, it should fail to style (Align) any other section. But the entire page is styled properly, short color. Also: Exception to the above is a body and a tag to give a universal feel in case I miss anything.

Comment: Hmm if it's not even parsing basic CSS then maybe it didn't download the CSS. Do you get the same results with other website analyzers?

Comment: It's parsing the CSS in terms of -format,- just not color. I'll update the post with a screenshot of what it sees. But, I see this exact same result on every analyzer I've come across: Google's, Pingdom's, Varvy's, etc. They all display the exact same thing -- well, Google tends to display a mobile version because they're mobile-centric these days. The mobile version looks perfectly aligned, -exactly- as it looks on an actual mobile device... but without color.

Comment: I am thinking the only possible source of this problem is either your code or your website network connection. You should post some snippets of your CSS and html, specifically the ones that are not rendering so that at least we can have a better idea of what the exact problem is. By the way, are using a lot of @import in your CSS? That could cause a network problem for crawlers.

Comment: I don't use @import at all. The only files I load in via CSS files are the fonts, which... as you can see, are loaded in just fine. The problem with displaying HTML and CSS is that literally -nothing- is being rendered in color. -Everything- is being rendered in black and white, properly aligned. I can throw in a couple of snippets, but to put it in perspective: The links are supposed to be orange and I just use color: rgb() to achieve that.

Comment: Uh. I'm glad you asked for a snippet. I forgot I recently swapped away from rgb() to using CSS custom properties. So instead of color: rgb(...) for links, it's color: var(--link), where --link stores the rgb() value. I just minified the alternative (rgb) and it shows up properly in the snapshot as orange now. So I'd say the crawler doesn't comprehend CSS custom properties... interesting. Will have to see if I can work around that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154837/discussion-between-i-r-r-and-drake-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out crawlers don't comprehend CSS custom properties yet. Using custom properties instead of traditional CSS revokes color for crawlers. So, learning that, I get to figure out how to fix CSS for agents lacking support for custom properties.

Added note: Internet Explorer doesn't support CSS Custom Properties (Latest version at the time of writing: IE11). Edge didn't until EdgeHTML 15. https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/03/24/css-custom-properties/

I've verified Opera, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome do support CSS custom properties (And have for at least a year -- most of the above for multiple years), so it's the same old story: Microsoft's way behind. If you have to build for IE or previous versions of Edge... find a solution for them. It'll be the same solution for site crawlers.